# JQuery function - run on click and on page load for specific radio button

Tags: jquery

New to JQuery and I have the following function.  I am trying to modify it so it does 2 things: Not trigger the function when I click other radio buttons (I thought '#UpdateType input[type="radio"]' would do this) and also run the function on load as well as on click.  #UpdateType is the ID for the radio buttons I'm using this with.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(updateTypeFunc);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#UpdateTypeRB input[type="radio"]').click(updateTypeFunc);
});
function updateTypeFunc()
{
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'UpdateType' && $(this).val() == 'Current') {
        $('.current-employee').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.current-employee').hide();
    }
}
```

As of right now it fires when I click any radio button regardless of the ID.

Edit: HTML

```
<div class="col-md-10" id="UpdateTypeRB">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select whether the employee is new or current." id="UpdateType" name="UpdateType" type="radio" value="New"> New
    </label>
    <br>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input checked="checked" class="btn btn-secondary" id="UpdateType" name="UpdateType" type="radio" value="Current"> Current
    </label>
    <br>
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="UpdateType" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Razor:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UpdateType, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UpdateType, "New", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) New
        </label>
        <br />
        <label class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UpdateType, "Current", new { @class = "btn btn-secondary" }) Current
        </label>
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UpdateType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit 2: Updated JQuery thanks to @KristianBarrett.  Works other than the $(document).ready I tried to implement.

What I'm overall trying to achieve is hiding / showing certain required elements on the page based on this radio button tick.  It initially loads with none checked so the user is forced to pick one.  I then use Foolproof to do RequiredIf's based on those check boxes (the 'Current' tick) and want to show them to the user after 'Current' is ticked with JQuery.  The problem is when validation throws an ErrorMessage after the Submit, the Current checkbox is ticked still however the fields are hidden until I manually click it again.  The fields are hidden by default.

Comment: Whats your HTML look like? `$('#UpdateType input[type="radio"]')` says run this handler for any radio inside the container with ID of `UpdateType`

Comment: Edited. So would that mean my Razor syntax is screwing it up because of the two ID's of #UpdateType?

Comment: Well yeah - you can't have two of the same ID - **ID's must be unique**

Comment: I understand what that `$('#UpdateType input[type="radio"]')` means now.  What about having multiple methods of calling that function, such as onload and onclick?

Comment: You can shorthand trigger the function on load by suffixing your handler with a `.click()` - `$('#UpdateType input[type="radio"]').click(function () { }).click();`

Comment: Another question is why would you bind two different radio buttons to the same model property? I mean this is why you get two dom elements with same id.

Comment: I'm really pushing myself out of my comfort zone in programming to learn MVC and JQuery, so I'm imagining that I'm not doing everything fully correctly.  I am fully open to constructive criticism!  :)  I like to try to do things the right way but have been getting stuck.

Comment: @justiceorjustus Can you make an edit and try to explain what is you are trying to achieve? The problem with binding two radio buttons to the same property, is that your form will take the last value and put it in the property and then ignore the first (afaik). You should put them in different properties on your model.

Comment: Updated to try to add clarity, I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make two different options:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UpdateType, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UpdateType, "New", new { @class = "btn btn-primary new" }) New
    </label>
    <br />
    <label class="radio-inline">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UpdateType, "Current", new { @class = "btn btn-secondary current" }) Current
    </label>
    <br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UpdateType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Then you can apply `@checked = true` to your radio button you want to have clicked at page load. Like this

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UpdateType, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @checked = true })
```

When you bind your values to two different values on your model, then your server will parse the selected one, and should set them correctly once it returns your view.

After that you need to apply the answer stweb gave you, but you need to look for the checked one.

So you should do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
        clickFunc($(this));   
    }); 
    clickFunc($('input[type=radio]:checked'));
});

function clickFunc($element){
    var currentEmployee = $('.current-employee');
    if ($element.attr('class').indexOf('current') !== -1) {
        currentEmployee.show();
    }
    else {
        currentEmployee.hide();
    }
}
```

you need to reapply the javascript everytime the page runs. So you iterate your check boxes and finds the checked one and clicks it.

```
$('input[type=radio]:checked')
```

this will give you the checked radio button. Then you can pass it to the clickFunc on `$(document).ready()`

EDIT:

Another thing you are doing is hardcoding against some specific IDs. You should rather think more generally. Like selecting all the radio buttons and then finding the checked one. This makes your code less error prone, when you change your ID of the model. The more generally you can make the code, the less you have to maintain.

Comment: There's a few things I ran into when trying to implement this.  First, it is allowing me to check both radio buttons at once.  Second, the jquery does not function even when that radio button is ticked.  This is probably because the ID of UpdateType is now CurrentType.  Even so when pointing at #CurrentType since the model changed, it does not show or hide. Edit: Also, it does tick the correct one when it gets to the view after validation errors (at least visibly) when using UpdateType twice. Still, I believe you that it is an incorrect way to do it and would like to do it the right way.

Comment: Sorry it has been a long day. Of course you were right by binding them to the same model actually, which makes you able to only select one. I will update it give me a min.

Comment: In reality, my only problem at this moment is firing my jquery function (edited my current JS in my original post which works for clicks) on page load at this moment. The model and view seem fine.

Comment: @justiceorjustus try it out now. I added classes instead of checking on the value. Actually you should split it into two click functions and attach it via the class of the radiobutton instead. Since your radio buttons does not share any functionality.

Comment: The javascript is not firing correctly on click, however it is firing correctly on page load for the "Current" checkbox.

Comment: @justiceorjustus I applied it to every radiobutton now. Normally you should apply clicks on classes, since they can repeat on dom elements and IDs should be unique.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for your time and persistence. I had to make a slight modification because I have more groups of radio buttons on the page and it would fire on those radio button clicks and hide it again.  I just wrapped an ID around the two buttons. Learned a lot here!

Answer (score 1):

To trigger on load try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $radioButton = $('#UpdateType input[type="radio"]');
    $radioButton.click(function () {
        clickFunc($(this));   
    }); 
    clickFunc($radioButton);
});

function clickFunc($element){
    var currentEmployee = $('.current-employee');
    if ($element.attr('id') == 'UpdateType' && $element.val() == 'Current') {
        currentEmployee.show();
    }
    else {
        currentEmployee.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is really not a good idea. Instead you should refactor the insides of the click function out in a new function(clickFunc). Then call said clickFunc, instead of triggering a click on the button.

Comment: Technically this works but not in the way I'm imagining.  Right now I have no radio buttons selected so I can validate in MVC that they have to click one.  This just checks the radio button right off the bat which fires the function above it, correct?  My problem is when validation in MVC comes back and reloads the form, it doesn't fire that function when the 'Current' radio button is checked and kept from the previous model.

Comment: @KristianBarrett, thanks, agree with your comment. Updated.

Comment: @justiceorjustus, do you mean you need to check the button after validation if the button was checked?

Comment: @stweb Yes, that is pretty much it.  I updated my post for more clarification. Edit: Well, it stays checked but does not fire my function and show those fields again.